# Mocking es6 class method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I am testing an express app, and I have the following files:

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const apiRouter   = require('./api');

const app = express();       
app.use('/api',apiRouter);


module.exports = app;
```

*api.js*

```
const Router = require( 'express').Router;
const CompanyController =require( './CompanyController');

const router = Router();

router.route('/company/registration').post(CompanyController.register);

module.exports=router;
```

*CompanyController.js*

```
class CompanyRegistration {
    constructor() {}


    static async register(req, res) {
        //some implementations
       //if successfull returns status code 200 or 422 if cant process

}
```

*registration.js*

```
import Request from 'supertest';
import app from   './app';
import CompanyController from './CompanyController';

const mockComp = jest.fn();
CompanyController.mockImplementation(()=>{
    return {
        register:mockComp
    }
});


it("should work",()=>{


    return Request(app).post("/api/company/registration").then(response => {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
    });
});
```

What am trying to do is mock the register method in CompanyController and change the implementation so that it returns a status code of 200, but I get the error:

> TypeError: _CompanyController.default.mockImplementation is not a
>   function

How do I implement this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `mockImplementation` you need to have told Jest that `CompanyController` needs to be mocked (as described [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationfn-or-mockimplementationonce-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationoncefn)):

```
import CompanyController from './CompanyController';
jest.mock('./CompanyController'); // you miss this line
const mockComp = jest.fn();
CompanyController.mockImplementation(()=>{
    return {
        register:mockComp
    }
});
```

Comment: i get an error Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout. after edding jest.mock('./CompanyController');

Comment: I checked the other solutions about increasing the timeout,but even though i increase the timeout it does not.it gives me the same error timeout